# how to seperate routing path with request's value in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently writing an api that receives a request value from an Android client and returns a list of posts.

Among the request values of this api, there is a value that comes in the form of req.body.sortType, and I want to sort the list of posts in a different way according to this value and send it to the response value.

So I tried a way below, but it failed.

// index.js

```
const express = require("express");

const gatheringController = require("./gathering.ctrl");
const likeController = require("./like.ctrl");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/list/:id", function (req, res, next) {
    let id = req.params.id;

    if(id == 1) {
        gatheringController.sort1;
    } else if(id == 2) {
        gatheringController.sort2;
    } else {
        gatheringController.sort3;
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

// gathering.ctrl.js

```
let sort1 = async function (req, res) {
    res.send(1);
}
let sort2 = async function (req, res) {
    res.send(2);
}
let sort3 = async function (req, res) {
    res.send(3);
}

module.exports = {
    sort1: sort1,
    sort2: sort2,
    sort3: sort3,
}
```

The reason I'm trying this is because I'm trying to write different sorting criteria in one function, so the code gets too long and less readable.

Could you tell me which part of my code is wrong in this case?

Comment: You have to actually call your functions.  `gatheringController.sort1;` doesn't do anything.  You would need something like `gatheringController.sort1(req, res);`.

Comment: Oh that's a solution!! Thank you so much! :) @jfriend00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually call your functions. Something like this:

```
gatheringController.sort1;
```

doesn't actually do anything. You would need to call your function and pass it the arguments you declare like this:

```
gatheringController.sort1(req, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a reason for using `async` in your `sort1`, `sort2`, `sort3` functions.

Other than that everything seems fine.

You could simplify your code a bit:

```
// gathering.ctrl.js

// use const if not re-assigning
const sort1 = (req, res) => res.send(1);
const sort2 = (req, res) => res.send(2);
const sort3 = (req, res) => res.send(3);

module.exports = {sort1, sort2, sort3 }

----------------
// index.js

const express = require("express");

const gatheringController = require("./gathering.ctrl");
const likeController = require("./like.ctrl");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/list/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  gatheringController["sort" + req.params.id];
})

module.exports = router;
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: By the way, I recommend either using cameCase or inserting a `_` for filenames rather than using a `.` as this implies an extension.

Oh and you would need to do error handling on the `id` to make sure it is one of `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Oh the reason why I use async function is that sort1,2,3 is just a example to show what I want to do. In real code, I'm goint to use several sequelize's function. By the way, this code is not worked... the response is time-out...